# Fetching the <td> element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am able to fetch the text in TD element with class `< list_selected >` element using beautiful soup

```
soup.find_all(class_ = {"list_selected"})
```

I have to fetch the NAME part after that. There are number of similar blocks.

```
<tr>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 3px;padding-right:3px;" class="list_selected">1422</td>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 3px;padding-right:3px;" class="data">123456</td>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 3px;padding-right:3px;" class="data">NAME</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup.find_all("td", { "class" : "list_selected" })
```

This will fetch the `td` nodes for you. The result is a list of nodes according to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful soap has got a method called (.text) to get inner contents of a html file

I corrected your code below to get the inner text

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 soup1 = BeautifulSoup('<td align="left" style="padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;" class="list_selected">1422</td>',"lxml")

 second= soup1.find("td", {"class": "list_selected"}) #Finding td class

 name = second.text #Getting inner text contents of td class

 print name #Displays inner text
```

Hope you got everything correct :)